# Objective-C: How can I decode a unicode character back to a string?

Tags: objective-c, decode, unicode-string, nsstringencoding

I encode a string using `NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding` like this:

```
NSString *utf32BigEndianString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding]];
```

For example, this would give me the unicode `<00000041>` for the string `A`. So how can I got the string `A` back from the unicode `<00000041>`. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there isn't actually a utf32 big endian string - what you have is a string containing a programmer friendly display of an `NSData` containing some utf32 big endian data

You can get from an `NSData` to a `NSString` using `NSString`'s `initWithData:encoding:` method.

If you absolutely had to use that string you have there you'd probably need to first turn it back into an `NSData`.